# How do I know whether Josso 1 is successfully connected to LDAP?

Tags: josso

I have configured according the guide given in the Josso sites. However, I'm still confuse on how to determine whether the Josso is successfully connected to the ldap. Is it can be determine by using the partnerapp?

Answer (score 0):

After configuration of LDAP with JOSSO you can execute your partnerapp and there try to login with some LDAP user with the username/password stored in LDAP for the user. If you are able to login then the LDAP connection is fine.